# Cannot create pie chart in which all values are identical

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I am unable to create a pie chart in which all responses are identical, or, in other words, in which 100% of the responses are represented by a single value. When I try to create such a chart, for example with [this dataset](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1VYOom4A7PU4kG02s-wR3F6RvvgElNa-sSPjG6ZtLrmA/edit?usp=sharing) or this one:

[image: dataset]

I get the error message:

> Requires at least 2 column(s) but only 1 provided.

If I add a different value to the bottom, however, I am able to create a pie chart as normal.

Is there a workaround for this? Or is this a known bug and/or lack of foresight in the design of the application?

Comment: Apparently the problem occurs because the values aren't numbers. Please add a demo spreadsheet shared with anyone with the link to view only.

Comment: @Rubén I'm adding in a link, but I periodically clear out such junk files, so link depreciation will be an issue in the future. Unfortunately, the actual data I am working with does not involve number values (though maybe there's a way to code those in?).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to change the default behavior of the Insert a Chart feature from  Google Sheets, so please submit your feedback directly to Google by using Google Feedback

From Google Sheets web UI

1. Click **Help** then **Report a problem**
2. Complete the form and click **Send**

By the other hand, if you are open to do an extra step,

1. Create your chart as usual
2. On the Chart editor panel

   1. On the Chart type selector, select the 3D pie chart or another similar chart type
   2. Check the **Aggregate** checkbox

[image]